# get all data web with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

**I'm try get all data website but have erorr
Line Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Do you help me!**

```js
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("out22.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vnexpress.net/").get();
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("Title : " + title);
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link: links) {
      String url = link.attr("href");
      //System.out.println("\nLink: "+url);

      Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
      Elements title1 = doc1.select("h1[class=title_news_detail mb10]");
      Elements description = doc1.select("p[class=description]");
      Elements content = doc1.select("p[class=Normal]");
      String tieude = title1.text();
      String noidung = content.text();
      String mota = description.text();
      System.out.println(noidung);

      pw.println(tieude);
      pw.println("\n" + mota);
      pw.println("\n" + noidung);
      pw.close();
```

Comment: Try adding www. ex: https://www.vnexpress.net/

Comment: You are getting "/" in attr href, please add a try catch block also & a condition for "/"

Answer (score 0):

Your URL was using request header for filter connection. if you want get data from this, you should use selenium.